# Javascript: Check if array is an almost increasing sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration, comparison

I'm working on some Javascript challenges on Code Signal and came across this question:

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is
>   possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more
>   than one element from the array.**
>
> Note: sequence a0, a1, ..., an is considered to be a strictly
>   increasing if a0 < a1 < ... < an. Sequence containing only one element
>   is also considered to be strictly increasing.
>
> Example For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
>   almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false.
>
> There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to
>   get a strictly increasing sequence. For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the
>   output should be almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.
>
> You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing
>   sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly
>   increasing sequence [1, 3].

My approach is to iterate through the sequence array, check if the current element is greater than the next element, if so remove current element. Then, increment a counter, if counter is less than 2 return true, else return false.

Here is my code:

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    // If array has 1 or 2 elements it passes
    if(sequence.length <= 2) {
        return true;
    }

    // Keeps track of numbers removed
    let numberRemoved = 0;

    // Iterate through array, check if current element is greater than next element
    // If so, increment numberRemoved and remove current element
    for(let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {        
        if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) {
            numberRemoved++;

            // Removed element if it's greater than next element
            let removed = sequence.splice([i], 1);
            i = 0;

            console.log(sequence);
        }

    }

    // Second pass through the array checks if there are 2 or more out of order        
    // elements. Inefficient and sloppy, need to find a better approach
    for(let j = 0; j < sequence.length; j++) {
        if(sequence[j] >= sequence[j + 1]) {
            numberRemoved++;
        }
    }

    // If number is less than 2, the sequence passes
    if(numberRemoved < 2) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }  
}
```

This solution solves 17/19 test cases. I'm running into an edge case where some times if **i >= [i + 1]** the correct approach would be to remove **[i + 1]**, not **i**. For example:

- In the case of sequence: [3, 5, 67, 98, 3]
- For loops checks if 98 is >= 3
- Removes 98
- Sequence fails because [3, 5, 67, 3] fails
- In this case we shouldn't remove 98, we should remove 3
- Sequence then passes :    [3, 5, 67, 98] returns true
- For this edge case we don't want to do:     **let removed = sequence.splice([i], 1);**
- We want to do:    **let removed = sequence.splice([i + 1], 1);**
- This would remove 3
- [3, 5, 67, 98] returns true

How can I handle this edge case? In some cases if **sequence[i] >= [i + 1]** you need to remove **sequence[i]**, in other cases you need to remove **[i + 1]**. How can I solve this problem without using a second for loop and passes through the array a second time?

Comment: Check if `[i+1] < [i-1]`. If it is, then remove `[i+1]` instead of `[i]`.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a decreasing number is found, we need to determine which one of 2 consecutive numbers should be removed. It can either be:

1. Last number is too large
2. Current number is too small

If neither of them can fix the decrease, the array is already not a "almost increasing sequence", because it means at least another removal is required.

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  let removed = 0;
  let i = 0;
  let prev = -Infinity;
  
  // as long as removed less than 2 times, and i is under arrays length
  while(removed < 2 && i < sequence.length) {
    if(sequence[i] > prev) { // if current is bigger the previous
      prev = sequence[i]; // assign current to previous
      // remove the latter number, if it fixes the decrease
    } else if (i === sequence.length - 1 || sequence[i+1] > sequence[i-1]) {
      removed++; // increment removed
    } else if (i < 2 || sequence[i] > sequence[i-2]) {
      // remove the former number, if it fixes the decrease
      removed++;
      prev = sequence[i];
    } else {
      // neither option fixes the decrease, so at least 2 removal is needed
      return false;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return removed < 2; // true if removed are under 2
}

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1])); // false
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2])); // true
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([3, 5, 67, 98, 3])); // true
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([4, 3, 5, 67, 98, 3])); // false
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 4, 2, 3])); // true
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([10, 13, 2, 9])); // false
```

Comment: Good catch. I've removed the "It would fail" part from your answer, since it was fixed. Next time a comment on my answer, detailing the problem, would be nice.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I thought a comment would be more appropriate, too, but my account cannot add comments yet.

Answer (score 1):

The question is mainly "do we need to remove one item or less to get an increasing sequence?". So you don't actually need to remove anything, just count the number of items that need to be removed.

In addition, you need to continue the check without the out of sequence numbering failing the next checks. In this case, assign to `prev` the lower number between the current, and `prev`.

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  let removed = 0;
  let i = 0;
  let prev = -Infinity;
  
  // as long as removed less than 2 times, and i is under arrays length
  while(removed < 2 && i < sequence.length) {
    if(sequence[i] > prev) { // if current is bigger the previous
      prev = sequence[i]; // assign current to previous
    } else {
      prev = Math.min(prev, sequence[i]); // take the lowest
      removed++; // increment removed
    }
    
    i++;
  }

  return removed < 2; // true if removed are under 2
}

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1])); // false
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2])); // true
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([3, 5, 67, 98, 3])); // true
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([4, 3, 5, 67, 98, 3])); // false
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 4, 2, 3])); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to really understand the question, but I I think this one could be your answer....

```js
function testSequence(arraySequence)
  {
  let prev = -Infinity
    , ret  = true
    , out  = false
    ;
  for(let val of arraySequence) 
    {
    if (val<=prev)
      {
      if (out) { ret=false; break }
      else     { out=true         }
      }
    prev=val
    }
  return ret
  }


console.log(testSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]));         // false
console.log(testSequence([1, 3, 2]));            // true
console.log(testSequence([3, 5, 67, 98, 3]));    // true
console.log(testSequence([4, 3, 5, 67, 98, 3])); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a found index.

> This approach tests either three consecutive elements, like
>
> ```
>             v
> 1   2  [3   8   4]  5   6   7   -> found at index 3
> ```
>
> or takes for the next loop a check which omits the found value by checking the found index.
>
> ```
>                 v
> 1   2   3  [8   4   5]  6   7
>             ^ omit value on found index
> ```
>
> Then if not in sequence, the adjacent items are checked to prevent this pattern
>
> ```
>             v
> 1   2   3   1   2   5   6   7
>         3   >   2
>
>             v
> 1   2   3   8   2   5   6   7
>         3   >   2
> ```
>
> and if found, more than one element is in wrong position.

```js
function inSequence(array) {
    var i,
        found;
        
    for (i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if ((found === i - 1 || array[i - 1] < array[i]) && array[i] < array[i + 1]) continue;
        if (array[i - 1] >= array[i + 1] || found !== undefined) return false;
        found = i;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(inSequence([2, 1]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(inSequence([2, 1, 3]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 4, 3]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 9, 7]));
console.log(inSequence([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3, 8, 2, 5, 6, 7]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question asks that you find if when an index in an array is removed the array would be an increasing sequence. Therefore if we ignore an index that disobeys the rule

> a *i* < a *i+1*

then the other index should obey the rule.

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
let unorderedIndex = 0;
for(let i = 1; i < sequence.length; i++ ){
if( sequence[i-1] >= sequence[i] ) {
    unorderedIndex++;

// an array that's almost increasing would just have one unordered index
    if( unorderedIndex > 1 ) return false;
    
    if( sequence[i-2] >= sequence[i] && sequence[i-1] >= sequence[i+1])
        return false;
    }
} 
return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution.

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  // initialize removedCount to 0.
  let removedCount = 0;

  // iterate through sequence
  for(let i=0; i<sequence.length-1; i++) {
    // if current value is greater than the next value ex. [3, 1, 2]; 3 > 1
    if(sequence[i] > sequence[i+1]) {
      // increase count
      removedCount++;
    } 
  }
  // if our count is more than 2 return false, otherwise return true 
  return removedCount <= 1;
}
```

Comment: fails for [1,2,1,2]